# Better binning in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I've got a data frame and want to filter or bin by a range of values and then get the counts of values in each bin.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
x = 5
y = 17
z = 33
filter_values = [x, y, z]
filtered_a = df[df.filtercol <= x]
a_count = filtered_a.filtercol.count()

filtered_b = df[df.filtercol > x]
filtered_b = filtered_b[filtered_b <= y]
b_count = filtered_b.filtercol.count()

filtered_c = df[df.filtercol > y]
c_count = filtered_c.filtercol.count()
```

But is there a more concise way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [pandas.cut](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(50), columns=['filtercol'])
filter_values = [0, 5, 17, 33]   
out = pd.cut(df.filtercol, bins=filter_values)
counts = pd.value_counts(out)
# counts is a Series
print(counts)
```

yields

```
(17, 33]    16
(5, 17]     12
(0, 5]       5
```

---

To reorder the result so the bin ranges appear in order, you could use

```
counts.sort_index()
```

which yields

```
(0, 5]       5
(5, 17]     12
(17, 33]    16
```

Thanks to [nivniv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451185/better-binning-in-pandas/14451264#comment51709235_14451264) and [InLaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7084278/inlaw) for this improvement.

---

See also [Discretization and quantiling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#discretization-and-quantiling).

Comment: yes!  Is there a way to sort the index/keys of the resulting value_counts() object?

Comment: @unutbu counts.reindex(counts.index) won't work for me on another example. does it sort lexicographically?

Comment: No, `reindex` doesn't do any sorting. It relies on the order provided by `counts.index`. Perhaps it would be best to post a new question with a simple example demonstrating the problem and the desired output.

Comment: ok I think I figured it out with counts.sort_index(). Thanks though